# ReactiveUI commands : How to use canexecute with static conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

How can I do this equivalently with ReactiveUI commands?
And there especially deal with the IObservable equivalent CanExecute?

```
private readonly bool enableEdit = ctor-param;

this.AddIdCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddIdExecute, ()=>enableEdit);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is that static in value, do it like so:

```
this.AddIdCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(AddIdExecute, Observable.Return(enableEdit));
```